# O que é um arquivo YAML e quando devemos utilizá-lo?

Tags: yaml

Para quê serve um arquivo YAML e quando é adequado criá-lo em um projeto?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não foi dado contexto, mas se estiver falando de [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) é um formato de dados serializados que podemos dizer ser um concorrente do [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). Ele é mais simples e mais econômico.

Pode usar sempre que achar que atende todas suas necessidades. Em geral costuma ser um bom substituto para o JSON. Mas eu não usaria em coisas externas porque muita gente não saberá ou não terá como acessar este formato. JSON e XML se tornaram padrões universais, YAML não. Mas de forma geral gosto mais dele. Não tem um critério específico para adotá-lo em coisas internas que não precisarão se comunicar com nada que você não tenha controle.

O fato de menos pessoas usar torna mais difícil de achar informação e ajuda, mas também é rato precisar.

Apesar de mais simples ele é oferece mais que o JSON. Um pouco menos que o XML que é extremamente complexo.